# Retrieve custom elements with mgt-people-picker

Tags: microsoft-graph-toolkit

When using the `mgt-people-picker`, is there a way to retrieve extension properties that are defined for the selected user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At present there is not. If this is a feature that you'd like to see then please raise an issue on the repo and explain the scenario you'd like to have this feature for and how you'd expect to use it as developer integrating the component.

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-toolkit/issues